# Saving the content of old EditTexts inside the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a Recyclerview inside each row of which I have an editText , I have a plus button inside my activity that by pressing it , a row will added to the recyclerview , when I add a row and fill the edit text and press the plus button , a new row appears but the content of the old items disappear , how to save the content of all old item ??
Thanks

Comment: can you put your adapter code here?

Comment: @Farrokh it got solved